# What is used by bash to open/execute argv[0]?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I apologize in advance if this is a silly question, however the deeper I delve into it the more confused I am.  I am teaching myself C and recently been looking into file "open" related functions and macros in order to have a better understanding of what exactly takes place.

So, my dumb question is, on a system running Centos 6.6 and using the Bash shell, what exactly opens argv[0] for execution when a program is invoked from the command prompt?

I have experimented with (what I believe are referred to as) intercept programs and by exporting a shared object file via the LD_PRELOAD directive and can track at least some of the calls to "open" and "open64".

The debug style print statement I use gives me the filename being opened however I have noticed that the program being called from the command line (which I assume to be argv[0]) doesn't appear as if it being referenced by either of these.

This led me to start slogging through the bash source and not getting any real progress.

I would dearly appreciate any pointers on what I might need to look for and where?  I have grep'ed on argv, argv(, main(, execev, ioctl and fcntl, googled and searched message boards but am not making progress.

I would dearly appreciate any advice or pointers on this.

Comment: The `exec*` family of functions is what you want to track. Executing a file and opening it are two completely different things.

Comment: The shell `fork` a new process and `exec` the file, so it doesn't involve `open` at all.

Comment: The `exec*()` family of functions is responsible for reading the file specified as the first argument.  You won't see a separate user-level open operation; it is handled by the kernel internally.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense; the shell *doesn't* execute `argv[0]` at all in any meaningful way. The path to a command being invoked is a separate argument to the execv family of functions from its argument vector.

Answer (score 5):

Get the source for `bash` (note: it's not a simple shell - it's a very complex program):

- `git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/bash.git`.

Take a look at the file `execute_cmd.c` and the functions `execute_disk_command()` and `shell_execve()`.

Basically `execute_disk_command()` performs a `fork()` (via the helper function `make_child()` followed by an `execve()` (via `shell_execve()`).

Comment: Use xrefs if you want to browse it online: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/bash/execute_cmd.c#5192 and http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/bash/execute_cmd.c#4845

Answer (score 3):

Eventually, `execve()` is the entry point for all program invocations (on POSIX-compliant platforms). It instructs the operating system to run the loader, which prepares the new program for execution and eventually brings it into running state (and leaves it to itself). One argument provided to execve() is a character string — a file system path pointing to the executable file on disk. By convention, argv[0] is set to the corresponding basename*. The arguments are placed onto the stack of the newly spawned program, so that it can access them.

See http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve:

> int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const
>   envp[]);
>
> execve() executes the program pointed to by ***filename***. filename must be
>   either a binary executable, or a script starting with a line of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> #! interpreter [optional-arg]
> ```
>
> argv is an array of argument strings passed to the new program. By
>   *convention*, the first of these strings should contain the filename
>   associated with the file being executed.

Comment: The path to the executable file and argv[0] are not *necessarily* the same thing. It's conventional, but one can run file A and tell it its argv[0] is B.

Comment: Sure thing, I should have clarified that. Will update the answer.

Comment: As edited -- with the man page quote, in particular -- this is now authoritative; bravo.